# How to verify a Metaplex collection?

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js

So my NFT metadata's collection field is like this:

```
address: "string"
key: "string",
verified: false
```

Also the `collectionDetails` is null.

My question is how to verify the collection and how should I create it that the collectionDetails under nft's metadata has informative props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Currently with Metaplex, the recommended approach for grouping a collection by using the mint address of another NFT as the "Collection NFT". The Collection NFT has a `collectionDetails` field that identifies it as a "sized" collection. This field stores the number of verified NFTs that reference the Collection NFT in their respective `collection` fields.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections#collection-nfts

Here is an example of how to use the metaplex sdk to:

- create a collection NFT
- create a NFT as part of the collection
- verify the new NFT as part of the collection

  ```
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"))

  // Generate a new keypair to use for keypairIdentity
  const keypair = Keypair.generate()

  // Fund the keypair with some SOL
  const txSig = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    keypair.publicKey,
    1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
  )

  // Confirm airdrop
  const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
  await connection.confirmTransaction(
    {
      blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature: txSig,
    },
    "finalized"
  )

  // Set up metaplex
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
    .use(keypairIdentity(keypair))
    .use(
      bundlrStorage({
        address: "https://devnet.bundlr.network",
        providerUrl: "https://api.devnet.solana.com",
        timeout: 60000,
      })
    )

  // convert to metaplex file
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync("src/image.gif")
  const file = toMetaplexFile(buffer, "image.gif")

  // upload image
  const imageUri = await metaplex.storage().upload(file)
  console.log("Image URI:", imageUri)

  // upload metadata
  const { uri } = await metaplex.nfts().uploadMetadata({
    name: "My NFT",
    description: "My description",
    image: imageUri,
  })
  console.log("Metadata URI:", uri)

  // create collection NFT
  const collectionNft = await metaplex.nfts().create(
    {
      uri: uri,
      name: "Collection NFT",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
      isCollection: true, // <--- this sets it as a collection NFT
    },
    { commitment: "finalized" }
  )
  // When logged you should see collectionDetails in the nft metadata:
  // "collectionDetails: { version: 'V1', size: <BN: 0> }"
  console.log(collectionNft)

  // create NFT in collection
  const nftInCollection = await metaplex.nfts().create(
    {
      uri: uri,
      name: "NFT in Collection",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
      collection: collectionNft.mintAddress,
    },
    { commitment: "finalized" }
  )

  // verify nft as part of collection
  const verify = await metaplex.nfts().verifyCollection(
    {
      mintAddress: nftInCollection.mintAddress,
      collectionMintAddress: collectionNft.mintAddress,
      isSizedCollection: true,
    },
    { commitment: "finalized" }
  )

  // For some reason, "collectionDetails" doesn't show up in the explorers
  console.log(
    `Collection NFT:,
    https://explorer.solana.com/address/${collectionNft.mintAddress.toBase58()}/metadata?cluster=devnet`
  )

  // However, the "collection" field in the metadata will be "verified" for the Nft in collection
  console.log(
    `NFT in Collection:,
    https://explorer.solana.com/address/${nftInCollection.mintAddress.toBase58()}/metadata?cluster=devnet`
  )

  console.log(
    `Transaction Signature: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${verify.response.signature}?cluster=devnet`
  )
  ```

Not sure why, but the `collectionDetails` field for the Collection NFT does not appear on explorers. However, it is in the NFT metadata when logging it using the Metaplex SDK.

Collection NFT: https://explorer.solana.com/address/4RcsVbzbCMMVpAgnLX1EWgDaHYunRZCYVQTbg6sLzKBd/metadata?cluster=devnet

NFT in Collection: https://explorer.solana.com/address/8H1LLAGv5Ca2xXjhUTmtEYCLBM7vbkPbearVRWr1t2yi/metadata?cluster=devnet

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the solution code, specially adding the right libraries. Also with metaplex uploading. So I would like to contribute with a full executable code of john and jimi's metadata:
Name the script "mint.cjs"
Adding also a Devnet funded wallet.

```
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, Keypair } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Metaplex, keypairIdentity } = require("@metaplex-foundation/js");
const fs = require('fs');


// mint
const mint = async () => {

    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"))

    // Generate a new keypair to use for keypairIdentity
    const secret = [6, 75, 114, 41, 237, 21, 146, 239, 34, 199, 207, 63, 78, 73, 16, 187, 113, 38, 228, 73, 244, 253, 210, 84, 197, 26, 247, 50, 181, 61, 184, 221, 208, 236, 132, 116, 6, 84, 36, 102, 26, 230, 69, 156, 226, 121, 29, 12, 240, 33, 123, 145, 229, 194, 213, 51, 46, 233, 45, 36, 106, 221, 171, 221]
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secret));

    // Set up metaplex
    const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
        .use(keypairIdentity(keypair))

    // urls
    const metadataUri = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/main/metadata.json"

    // create collection NFT
    const collectionNft = await metaplex.nfts().create(
        {
            uri: metadataUri,
            name: "Collection NFT",
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
            isCollection: true, // <--- this sets it as a collection NFT
        },
        { commitment: "finalized" }
    )
    // When logged you should see collectionDetails in the nft metadata:
    // "collectionDetails: { version: 'V1', size: <BN: 0> }"
    console.log(collectionNft)

    // create NFT in collection
    const nftInCollection = await metaplex.nfts().create(
        {
            uri: metadataUri,
            name: "NFT in Collection",
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
            collection: collectionNft.mintAddress,
        },
        { commitment: "finalized" }
    )

    // verify nft as part of collection
    const verify = await metaplex.nfts().verifyCollection(
        {
            mintAddress: nftInCollection.mintAddress,
            collectionMintAddress: collectionNft.mintAddress,
            isSizedCollection: true,
        },
        { commitment: "finalized" }
    )

    // For some reason, "collectionDetails" doesn't show up in the explorers
    console.log(
        `Collection NFT:,
    https://explorer.solana.com/address/${collectionNft.mintAddress.toBase58()}/metadata?cluster=devnet`
    )

    // However, the "collection" field in the metadata will be "verified" for the Nft in collection
    console.log(
        `NFT in Collection:,
    https://explorer.solana.com/address/${nftInCollection.mintAddress.toBase58()}/metadata?cluster=devnet`
    )

    console.log(
        `Transaction Signature: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${verify.response.signature}?cluster=devnet`
    )

}


// mint
mint()
```