# Collection is not showing in solscan (minting nft in solana with collection using metaplex)

Tags: metaplex, nft, mint

I have minted a collection and nfts using some codes, and got to same result than those other stackoverflow questions. Nfts are ok, collection is there, but solscan is not showing it in the NFT sheet.

Here some examples that I found in devnet with the same problem:

Source:
[How to verify a Metaplex collection?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-to-verify-a-metaplex-collection)

Collection:
[https://explorer.solana.com/address/${collectionNft.mintAddress.toBase58()}/metadata?cluster=devnet](https://explorer.solana.com/address/$%7BcollectionNft.mintAddress.toBase58()%7D/metadata?cluster=devnet)

NFT:
[https://explorer.solana.com/address/${nftInCollection.mintAddress.toBase58()}/metadata?cluster=devnet](https://explorer.solana.com/address/$%7BnftInCollection.mintAddress.toBase58()%7D/metadata?cluster=devnet)

In the other hand, if I browse solscan, i found nfts with the collection reference under the royalty field:
https://solscan.io/token/6CwTUkH4NCc9d34NSusPMhKz7jnZVSq16ZDZakkWfWZF

I have reviewed all metadata in those examples and the Reavers nft, and found no difference.

Any thoughts on that?
Is it a problem of that those example NFTs just exists on Devent ?
Is there any action to be performed on solscan ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: is your collection verified ?

Comment: yes, it is ! at least its showing collection token and verified true in my nft metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection not showing on solscan is basically a problem with the explorer. It doesn't show collections on devnet. If you want to check if your code is correct try using https://translator.shyft.to/ explorer. Enter the wallet address that holds the NFT here and you should be able to see the collection your NFT is part of. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Tushar, If solscan its not showing collections on Devnet problem is solved. This means it all works in mainnet !
Thanks